# Need info about return -<options> in TCL

Tags: tcl

What are the options are available in TCL return command ? i could see -code -errorcode -errorinfo as options for return command.. but couldn't understand the difference between them.

```
proc new {} {
set name george
puts "Hello $name"
return -code ok
}
puts [new]
```

Here i didn't get any output, it is like normal return command. But could get more option for -code in return command like break , continue, error  and also retun... What is the use of this options. 
And also below code makes me confuse ..

```
proc new {} {
set name george
puts "Hello $name"
return -code return -code return -code return
}
```

like that we can give more , it didn't get errored , what is the use of this option..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options for `return` are listed on the man page: [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm).

`-errorcode`, `-errorinfo`, `-errorstack`, and `-level` are used to describe aspects of an exception: `-options` allows one to pass a dictionary of exception data to the command. Neither of these is likely to be useful to you until you have a thorough understanding of the language and are writing advanced exception handling code.

The `-code` option is used to specify what kind of handling surrounding code will need to perform. `ok` means that no special handling is necessary and that the result of the command is valid data; `error` means that a `catch` or `try` handler needs to be in place or the program will end, and also that the result of the command is an error message. `break` and `continue` need an enclosing looping command (or a `catch` / `try` command with an appropriate handler clause). `return` makes the command where it is used behave like a `return` command. You probably won't need to deal with this option unless you are writing your own control structures.

The `-level` option also lets the `return` command return to somewhere else than in the caller (but still in the call stack). If the value is 0, the return action is "in place": `return` will return from itself without terminating the script it is part of. The first line of

```
set foo [return -level 0 bar]
puts {I'm still alive}
```

will be executed as `set foo bar`, and evaluation will continue with the `puts` command. `-level 1` means return to the caller (the usual behavior), `-level 2` means return to the caller's caller, and so on.

The return command accepts just about anything in its argument list, and like many commands won't complain about arguments being repeated. `return -code return -code return -code return` does the same thing as `return -code return`.